# Select query in sqlite in android with two value in where clause

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to write  query in sqlite for android in which i want to get a value based upon two values of that row.How can i do that?
i have the following query to get value based on one value:

```
cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[] {NAME}, ROLL_NO + " like" + "'%" 
                + roll + "%'", null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

`cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[] {NAME}, ROLL_NO + " like" + "'%" + roll + "%' **OR** ", null, null, null, null)`

add your second clause after **OR** in above query

Answer (score 1):

BTW. Guys, have you thought about DB security (SQL injection attacks)? If `roll` is smth that user inputs or you get it from a potentially "dangerous" source (file or network), then I'd recommend to rewrite the code to the following:

```
db.query(
  TABLE_NAME,
  new String[] {NAME}, 
  ROLL_NO + " like " + "'%?%'",
  new String[] { String.valueOf(roll) },
  null, null, null
);
```

Doing this way the DB will "preprocess" the `roll` value before executing the query to ensure the value is safe to use. The safe value will be then inserted instead of the `?` char in the `ROLL_NO + " like " + "'%?%'"` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.   The following code worked for me:

```
public Cursor fetchMyValues() {
String DATABASE_TABLE="mytablename";
String depthVar="'50'";
String tempVar="'2.5'";
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "depth", "temp", "health"}, 
          "temp like " + tempVar + " AND " + "depth like" + depthVar, null, null, null, null);}
```

This would represent my sql:
    select health from mytablename where temp='2.5' and depth='50';

hmmm....
I suppose I could do this cleaner with int and/or double, using = instead of like.

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple try this actid,cusid is string and FF_CUSTOMER_ID,FF_ACTIVITY_ID is column name

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_PROJECT_ACTIVITY_CHECKLIST +" where " + FF_ACTIVITY_ID + " = ? AND " + FF_CUSTOMER_ID + " = ? " , new String[] { actid,cusid});